# List of area tags

Tags: discussion, tags

This post is to collect the area tags and discuss their use.

The goal of these tags to help people filter/search questions by diving them into reasonable subject categories. The idea is similar to categorizing used on other places like libraries, arXiv, AMS MSC, ACM CCS, etc.

---

To keep the system useful the number of area tags needs to be kept small and every question should preferable be tagged by at least one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggested list of area tags:

- discrete-mathematics/combinatorics, complexity-theory, algorithms, data-structures, formal-languages, automata-theory, logic, computability, information-theory, cryptography, computational-geometry, numerical-analysis, symbolic-computation,
- computational-engineering (and science), computation-finance, algorithmic-game-theory,
- distributed-computing, parallel-computing, neural-computing, evolutionary-computing,
- artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, computer-vision, computational-linguistics, natural-language-processing, knowledge-representation/reasoning, robotics,
- databases/database-theory, information-retrieval,
- computer-architecture/hardware-architecture, computer-networks/internet-architecture, operating-systems, information-networks/social-networks, security,
- human-computer-interaction, multimedia, sound, graphics,
- software-engineering, programming-languages.

Comment: What is this list based on, that is why do you think this is a good selection? Some of the proposed tags are broader than others (e.g. evolutionary-computing vs database-theory) and some even subsume others (e.g. algorithms and evolutionary-computing) so I have trouble seeing the desired level of granularity. And boy, that are many tags (40); we barely even have that many active tags!

Comment: I think you know the base (arxiv which is itself is based on ACM CCS), I don't think it matters that much at this point, this is a good *starting point*. It would be better to have suggested changes in separate answers. One way to improve it is to consider the undergrad CS courses and see how they fit into these areas.

Comment: We are using around 25 of these but I included the other ones to make the list comprehensive. We can reduce the number but we would need to combine related tags like automata-theory and formal-languages. (I don't think it is a subarea of the other though they do have intersection. We can combine them if the general opinion leans towards that, though it might be good to get some advice from people more familiar with these area before doing that.)